# $1 - \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{2}{x^2} \left( 1 - \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \right) p \right)^{kx^2}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I'm currently working on my master thesis and I need to solve this limit.
I forgot almost everything about limits since last time a I saw them was basically in high school.
Anyway, I solved this limit with wolfram and it gives:

$1 - \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{2}{x^2} \left( 1 - \exp \left(  -\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \right) p \right)^{kx^2} = 1 - \exp(-2 k p)$

$k$ and $p$ are two parameters and, in particular, $k>0$, $p \in (0,1)$.

I'd like to have a step-by-step solution of the limit, or at least I'd like to know which method I could use to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you familiar with Taylor representation?

Comment: I remember I used Taylor representation to solve limits ($\sin(x) \approx x$), you suggest I should try it?

Comment: Yes. Consider Taylor representation for $\exp\left(-\dfrac{x^2}{2} \right)$ then it will be easier.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this, is it the same for $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$?

Comment: I was able to find the series expansion for $x \to 0$, but not for $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We shall use the expansion $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.
Write $$
\begin{align*}\left( 1 - \frac{2}{x^2} \left( 1 - \exp \left(  -\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \right) p \right)^{kx^2} &= \exp\left\{kx^2\log \left(1-\frac{2p}{x^2}+\frac{2p}{x^2e^{x^2/2}}\right)\right\} \\
&= \exp\left(kx^2\left(-\frac{2p}{x^2}+\frac{2p}{x^2e^{x^2/2}} + O(x^{-4}) \right)\right) \text{ as } x \rightarrow \infty \\
&= \exp\left(-2pk + 2pke^{-x^2/2} + O(x^{-2})\right)\\
&\rightarrow \exp(-2pk) \text{ as } x \rightarrow \infty
\end{align*}
$$

Hence,

$$1-\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left( 1 - \frac{2}{x^2} \left( 1 - \exp \left(  -\frac{x^2}{2} \right) \right) p \right)^{kx^2} = 1 - \exp(-2kp)$$

Comment: wow, this is genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: I have one question. If $\log(1-x) \approx x$, why on the second line we don't change the sign of $-\frac{2p}{x^2} + \frac{2p}{x^2 e^{x^2 /2}}$?

Comment: I understand it is correct to not change the sign, but why?

Comment: @Babababa31 you're right, the sign is bothering, use $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ instead. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you again!